# G Suite Marketplace App: detail page installation (Via User who admins multiple G Suite instances)

Tags: google-chrome, google-oauth, google-chrome-app, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

Given that a user is the super-administrator of multiple G Suite instances; they then auth into the admin console for *both* of these instances.

They then navigate to the detail page for a G Suite Marketplace App (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/[ID]), and it appears that whichever G Suite instance for which the user auth'd into the admin console **first** is defaulted as the domain for which the viewed G Suite Marketplace App will be installed.

[Screenshot: Defaulted account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIK7T.png)

Attempting to use the supplied account picker to switch to the non-defaulted account redirects the user to the associated (non-defaulted) admin console.

Based on these observed behaviors, there does not appear to be a viable route to drive a user in the given state to install a particular G Suite Marketplace App for the non-defaulted domain. Is this accurate?

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same behavior, I was able to find a temporary workaround: 
https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FAccountChooser%3Fcontinue%3D<your-marketplace-app-install-encoded-url>. 
(copy and paste the link address in an editor) This link will sign out of all current accounts (will not remove them from the 'cached account list'), then it will redirect to the Account Chooser, and finally redirect to MarketPlace app:

Comment: If anyone else is aware of this issue, please star it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67884428

Comment: Holy cats, I've confirmed that this does indeed work. Thanks! (I've already starred the issue).

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! For us, however, this solution doesn't stick. We're still waiting on Google to take a look at this and hopefully just fix it.

Comment: Agreed - this is not a solution for us, so much as a temporary workaround. Still: thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use this link:
https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FAccountChooser%3Fcontinue=

This link will sign out of all current accounts (will not remove them from the 'cached account list'), then it will redirect to the Account Chooser, and finally redirect to your MarketPlace app (notice the last redirect where you have to replace the stub).